# Lua and RSA encryption

Tags: encryption, lua, cryptography, rsa

I've been working on an RSA encryption script in Lua, with the assistance of BigNumbers (http://oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/bn/index.htm), and I pretty much have a working code. I'm stuck, however, because in a small percentage of cases, the encrypted original message is not decrypted to the original message, and I cannot figure out why. Please note that this will deal with very large numbers (1.08e107, for example). The entire code I've written is below, but here's a breakdown of what it should do.

```
print(rsa_getkey())

p: 83
q: 23
n: 1909
e: 19
d: 1899
phi: 1804
```

The above sets the key values, in which the public key is represented by [n, e] and the private key is represented by [n, d]. This is accomplished with the following code:

```
function rsa_getkey()
  rsa_e = 0
  local primes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 57, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}

  math.randomseed = os.time()

  rsa_p = primes[math.random(5,#primes)]
  rsa_q = rsa_p

  while rsa_q == rsa_p do
      math.randomseed = os.time()
      rsa_q = primes[math.random(5,#primes)]
  end

  rsa_n = rsa_p*rsa_q
  rsa_phi = (rsa_p-1)*(rsa_q-1)

  while rsa_e == 0 do
      local prime = primes[math.random(1,10)]
      if rsa_phi%prime > 0 then
          rsa_e = prime
      end
  end

  for i = 2, rsa_phi/2 do
      if ((i*rsa_phi)+1)%rsa_e == 0 then
          rsa_d = ((i*rsa_phi)+1)/rsa_e
          break
      end
  end
  return "p: ",rsa_p,"\nq: ",rsa_q,"\nn: ",rsa_n,"\ne: ",rsa_e,"\nd: ",rsa_d,"\nphi: ",rsa_phi,"\n"
end
```

After the keys have been determined, you can encrypt the message. In order to convert plain text ("Hello world") to a numeric system, I've created a function that isn't 100% complete, but works in the most basic form:

```
print(rsa_plaintext("Hello_world"))

1740474750625850534739
```

The following function is how that message is determined:

```
function rsa_plaintext(x)
  local alphanum = {A=10, B=11, C=12, D=13, E=14, F=15, G=16, H=17, I=18, J=19, K=20, L=21, M=22, N=23, O=24, P=25, Q=26, R=27, S=28, T=29, U=30, V=31, W=32, X=33, Y=34, Z=35, a=36, b=37, c=38, d=39, e=40, f=41, g=42, h=43, i=44, j=45, k=46, l=47, m=48, n=49, o=50, p=51, q=52, r=53, s=54, t=55, u=56, v=57, w=58, x=59, y=60, z=61, _=62}
      rsa_cipher = ""
  for i = 1, #x do
      local s = x:sub(i,i)
      rsa_cipher = rsa_cipher .. alphanum[s]
  end
  return rsa_cipher
end
```

Lastly, in order to make this much more manageable, I have to break it down into segments. In an effort to save time and code, I've combined the actual encryption with the conversion from plaintext to numeric format to encryption, though I've added decryption for debugging purposes. The code also accounts for affixing 0's to message to ensure 4 digits in each grouping. This is where my problem comes in; the Msg and Decrypted should be identical.

```
print(rsa_group("Hello world"))

Msg: 1740
Encrypted: 1560
Decrypted: 1740

Msg: 4747
Encrypted: 795
Decrypted: 929

Msg: 5062
Encrypted: 1659
Decrypted: 1244

Msg: 5850
Encrypted: 441
Decrypted: 123

Msg: 5347
Encrypted: 429
Decrypted: 1529

Msg: 3900
Encrypted: 1244
Decrypted: 82
```

This is done with the following two functions:

```
function rsa_group(str)
  local cipher = {}
  local str = rsa_plaintext(str:gsub(" ","_"))
  local len = #str
  local fillin = ""
  if len%4 ~= 0 then
      fillin = string.rep(0,(4-len%4))
  end
  str = str..fillin
  for i = 1, #str, 4 do
      local s,e = i, i+3
      local part = str:sub(s,e)
      print(rsa_encrypt(part))
  end
end

function rsa_encrypt(msg)
  bnrsa_e = BigNum.new(rsa_e)
  bnrsa_n = BigNum.new(rsa_n)
  bnmsg = BigNum.new(msg)
  result = 0
  quo = BigNum.new()
  rsa_c = BigNum.new()
  result = BigNum.pow(bnmsg, bnrsa_e)
  BigNum.div(result, bnrsa_n, quo, rsa_c)

  bnrsa_c = BigNum.new(rsa_c)
  bnrsa_d = BigNum.new(rsa_d)
  result = 0
  quo = BigNum.new()
  rsa_C = BigNum.new()
  result = BigNum.pow(bnrsa_c, bnrsa_d)
  BigNum.div(result, bnrsa_n, quo, rsa_C)

  return "Msg:",msg,"\nEncrypted:",rsa_c,"\nDecrypted:",rsa_C,"\n"
end
```

Now, I know this is a long question, and there are many components to the problem itself. I'm just at a loss how to figure out where my problem lies. Is there something I'm missing? A fresh set of eyes might be my solution.

Comment: Just to make sure it's not globals that's causing subtle bugs how about packaging those rsa parameters into a table and pass that table around?

Comment: Didn't think about that, though since it happens on a clean setup (i.e., no other variables present), it's not a global issue. But you're right, a table would probably be cleaner anyway.

Comment: RSA encryption requires that the message M you are encrypting is relatively prime to the RSA modulus. With normal cryptographic-sized parameters that event has such a vanishingly small probability it isn't worth checking for, but with such small numbers as you are using  it will happen frequently.

Comment: Hmm... so in short, I have two options - either use larger numbers, or check to see the relative prime connection? Wasn't aware that it required M to be relatively prime to the modulus. Will be interesting then...

Comment: You may be interested in checking out my [lbn](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbn), which uses  OpenSSL's bignumber library: one of the examples in the test code is RSA with big primes.

Comment: Is this code only for fun or for security? Textbook RSA like this is only for education, but not actually secure.

Comment: @GregS There is no requirement for `M` to be relatively prime to the modulus, though the exponent must be relatively prime to `phi(n)`.

Comment: The code is mostly for fun, not for security. @lhf, I'll definitely check it out, though I have a hate-hate relationship with buiilding using makefile, hah. I think greatwolf hit it, though. Didn't occur to me that M had to be less than n. Learned something today!

Comment: @Iridium: Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon closer examination it looks like the message `M` has to be [less than the product](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Encrypting_messages) `n` of your two primes. In your above test cases, all the messages except the first failed to decrypt properly because they're greater than `n = 1909`.

For example, consider where `M` just exceeded `n = 1909`:

```
Msg: 1910
Encrypted: 1
Decrypted: 1

Msg: 1911
Encrypted: 1222
Decrypted: 2

Msg: 1912
Encrypted: 1179
Decrypted: 3
```

In a real-world example, `n` is of course significantly larger and so this problem is much less likely to arise.

Comment: For handling a long message, just divide it into small blocks.

Comment: @lhf Don't invent an ECB like mode for RSA. That's slow and insecure. Create a random AES key, encrypt the actual message with AES and the AES key with RSA.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, real RSA has random padding, so it is not quite the same as ECB, even with no interaction between blocks.

Comment: @finnw I know. That's why I said "ECB like" not "ECB". It's still a dubious mode.